# Getting the number of digits of an integer

Tags: c

```
  bool isValidId(int* id)
  {
        if(log10(*id) != 6)
        {
           return false;
        }

   return true;
  }


  printf("Enter ID: ");
  gets(input);
  c.id = atoi(input);
  validID= isValidId(c.id);
  if(!validID)
  {
     printf("Invalid ID format -(Use example 123456 format). \n");
  }
```

This is how it looks now.I ask the user to enter an ID and check it if is valid with the isValidId method but my program is crashing when I enter an ID. Please help! Thanks

Comment: `log10` is good for that.

Comment: You can keep dividing by 10 to do the logarithm manually... that's actually not as slow as it sounds, but it can be optimized further if performance is critical.

Comment: In case you're wondering, Kerrek is probably talking about the function described in http://vimeo.com/55639112 (around 30m).

Comment: how can that be done in this method? :S I never heard of it

Comment: @Zeta: I have no idea, since I can't read a video link, but you can do things like dividing by higher powers of 10 to eat up large chunks of the number in one go. Facebook's Folly library does something related for string formatting (i.e. format two decimal digits at a time with a larger lookup table), since dividing (which is actually multiplication, since you're dividing by a constant) is the bottleneck.

Comment: For reference, the slides for that talk are here: http://www.slideshare.net/andreialexandrescu1/three-optimization-tips-for-c-15708507 (and they match the tips given by @KerrekSB)

Comment: @KerrekSB: The video is a talk by Andrei Alexandrescu, and he's showing exactly what you just said (formatting two digits at once, telling that dividing is actually multiplication) etc ;). Also I believe that Alexandrescu write that part of Facebook's Folly library.

Comment: Hey, I'm starting to recognize this now that I have the slides. I think I skimmed through them at one point.

Comment: For one, you're passing an `int` into something that takes a `int *`. That can't be good.

Comment: how can i pass an int* ?

Comment: I'm not sure why it takes `int *` in the first place.

Comment: @chris you can pass and int* by dereferencing a int variable with '&'

Comment: @kenny, But what's stopping the change to taking `int` and using `id` instead of `*id`?

Comment: @chris, the argument should be an int and not an int* IMO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
return *id >= 100000 && *id < 1000000;
```

I think this may be a good solution, both easy to read and efficient.

There is no need to acquire its length if you just want to judge if it is a valid id

Program crashes because the parameter of isValidId is pointer to int, not int, so

```
validID = isValidId(c.id);
```

should be

```
validID = isValidId(&c.id);
```

Comment: +1: Why bother counting digits when you just need a simple range-check? Good one :).

Comment: Way to actually think about the situation at hand. Sure if you need to actually calculate the length, you can do something else, but we're only interested in a length of 6 here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't see any reason to pass a pointer to `isValidId` function. You can pass an integer and calculate the number of digits.

```
bool isValidId(int id) {
    // count digits here
}
```

Now there are at least two ways to calculate the number of digits. First one is to use `log10`. The number of digits in a 10-base integer n is `(int)(log10(n) + 1)`. You will need to import `math.h` to use `log10`. You may check whether `n <= 0` before calling `log10`.

The second way is to loop through `n`.

```
int count = 0;

while (n > 0) {
    count++;
    n /= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You've declared `isValidId` to take a pointer to an `int`, but you're passing it a plain `int`; in this case, there's no reason to use a pointer, so you'd be better off changing `isValidId` to use a regular `int`.
2. **NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER USE GETS -- IT *WILL* INTRODUCE A POINT OF FAILURE/MAJOR SECURITY HOLE IN YOUR CODE**.  Use `fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)` instead.
3. How is `input` declared?  Is it large enough to hold as many digits as `int` will allow, plus a sign, plus a 0 terminator?
4. `log10` returns a `double`, not an `int`.  To properly count digits with `log10`, you will need to write something like  `(int)floor(log10(id)) + 1`.

You can simplify your `isValidId` function a little:

```
bool isValidId(int id)
{
  return (int) floor(log10(id)) + 1 == 6;
}
```

The Boolean data type is a latecomer to the C language (introduced in C99), so a lot of us older types tend to avoid using Boolean constants in our code.

Answer (score 0):

I've not done C for eons however try something like this

```
bool isValidId(int* id)
{
    char str[15];
    sprintf(str, "%d", id)
    if(strlen(str) != 6)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Almost, but `sprintf` doesn't return the string, so you have to work around that.

Comment: @chris thanks for pointing that out like I said been many years, I've corrected the code

Answer (score -1):

It's way easier like this:

```
#include <math.h>
bool isValidId(int *id)
{
    return (int)log10(*id) == 6;
}
```

Comment: `id` is `int`, `atoi` converts from string to `int`. What the heck are you doing here? `itoa` is probably what you mean (int to string), but it is not standard C.

Comment: Sorry, should be itoa. Got it wrong. He was using atoi, so I thought he must do it this way.

Comment: What compiler has `itoa` with such function signature? If you can gives a link to a documentation that lists `itoa` with the above signature, I'll consider it valid. Can only find this `char *  itoa ( int value, char * str, int base );`

Comment: Note that `log10` returns floating point number. You need to cast it back to `int` before doing the comparison.